# JTextArea.append() method returns a null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jtextarea

I am working on a game in java, and have created a JTextArea to display the majority of text, along with a textPrinter method to append text to the JTextArea. However whenever i try to call textPrinter i get a null pointer exception. I know that the string i'm passing into the method isn't null as when System.out.println(text) is run from the textPrinter method it shows that the value was passed correctly.

**Related code from my main class:**

```
public class stickGame {

public JTextArea gameText;
public JPanel gamePanel;
public JFrame gameWindow;

public static void main(String[] args) {
stickGame game = new stickGame();
TextHandler text = new TextHandler();
gameEnabled = true;

while (gameEnabled == true) {

    MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
    victory = false;

    //SinglePlayer Logic
    if (gameMode == 1) {

        gameLevel = 0;

        while (defeat != true) {

            playerHealth = 100;
            aiHealth = 100 + (25 * gameLevel);
            pRage = 0;
            aiRage = 0 + (10 * gameLevel);
            secondPRage = 0;
            secondPlayerHealth = 100;
            text.textPrinter("Level "+ (gameLevel + 1)+"\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Code from my TextHandler Class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TextHandler extends stickGame {

private String pText;

public void WindowHandler() {

    gameWindow = new JFrame("Stick Game");
    gameWindow.setVisible(true);
    gameWindow.setSize(1000, 600);

    gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 120));
    gamePanel.setVisible(true);

    gameText = new JTextArea();
    gameText.setSize(600, 600);
    gameText.setLineWrap(true);
    gameText.setVisible(true);
    gameText.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));

    JButton attackB = new JButton("Attack");
    JButton blockB = new JButton("Block");
    JButton rushB = new JButton("Rush");
    JButton healB = new JButton("Heal");
    JButton ultimateB = new JButton("Ultimate");
    JButton cheatB = new JButton("Cheat");

        attackB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveChoice = "attack";
            duplicateCheck = true;
            }
        });

        blockB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                playerMoveChoice = "block";
                duplicateCheck = true;
                }
        });

        rushB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                playerMoveChoice = "rush";
                duplicateCheck = true;
                }
        });

        healB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveChoice = "heal";
            duplicateCheck = true;
            }
        });

        ultimateB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveChoice = "ultimate";
            duplicateCheck = true;
            }
        });

        cheatB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pRage = stickGame.pRage + 100;
            }
        });

    gamePanel.add(gameText);
    gamePanel.add(attackB);
    gamePanel.add(blockB);
    gamePanel.add(rushB);
    gamePanel.add(healB);
    gamePanel.add(ultimateB);
    gamePanel.add(cheatB);
    gameWindow.add(gamePanel);
    gameWindow.repaint();
 }


 public void textPrinter(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
    gameText.append(text);
 }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TextHandler.textPrinter(TextHandler.java:113)
    at stickGame.main(stickGame.java:431)
```

The null pointer exception occurs at the text.textPrinter("Level "+ (gameLevel + 1)+"\n"); in the main method. What exactly is the problem and how should i go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Your JTextArea is constructed in the method WindowHandler, which is never called.  Either call WindowHandler() after constructing TextHandler or call it from the constructor of TextHandler

Comment: I had forgotten to add that in, it was right after the textPrinter() call, so when i was trying to call the method i hadn't initialized it yet. Thanks XD